# Creating a Drop Down List for An Already Existing Data Table with Over 3500 Line Items (Rows)

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Sorry to bother you. I really could not find an answer on Reddit or Google.

So I provided an example of the Table I am working with. Except my current data set is not just 11 Rows across. I have over 3500 Lines (Rows/ Line Items) that exist already.

Please see attached/ Picture uploaded

Essentially I want:

I) Excel to automatically recognize and grab the address for the existing 3500 lines (Current example with screenshot is that I have 11 entered) entered onto spreadsheet and with those correctly grabbed addresses shown as a drop down menu in Column B (Site Location). So in column B for the already entered addresses, the cell will[image] look like it has a drop down menu to choose from?

II) With new line items being entered after Row 12 beginning Row 13 that Site Location (Column B) will also have a drop down menu for those entering the new data into Column B (Site Location).

III) Type of Personnel column will also have a dropdown menu for the existing data and new data to be entered.

Is this possible? Or am I dreaming beyond the capabilities of Excel?

Thank you!!

Comment: If you press `CTRL` and the down arrow simultaneously  while in a list column, Excel will automatically give you a drop down of list items; however, you won't see a drop down arrow in the cell. This might be an alternative for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the cells in colum B (or the whole column) and then add a data validation rule that references the same column as a list.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249 for how to create a data validation.

Select the "list" option for the validation, then define the column B as the list. Make sure the check mark is set on "In-cell dropdown".

Then you'll have a dropdown list with the already present values in the column.

You can also add new values because they will become part of the list that validates the entries.

Comment: Thank you I figured it out. Sorry it took awhile because I was on a different project. I basically created a list and removed duplicate addresses. Then used a list without duplicate addresses to create the drop-down list. So simple sigh wish I found out sooner. Probably would have saved me some headaches.... Thank you!